# How does HTML java applet finds its .jar?

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet, classpath

I have this code:

```
document.write("<APPLET CODE='com/synergex/My.class' ARCHIVE='toc2.jar' ");
```

When my "toc2.jar" is in the same folder as the HTML - all works fine.

But when I put "toc2.jar" in another folder ("C:\MyJars"), I get `ClassNotFoundException`.

How can I "tell" the browser where to look for jars?

I tried to add "C:\MyJars" or "C:\MyJars\toc2.jar" to my `CLASSPATH` env variable, but it did not work.

Comment: There is a good [library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) to include applets to websites dynamically. maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

You ***might*** be able to redirect the code base using an [HTML `base` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4).

> For example, given the following `BASE` declaration and `A` declaration:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
   <TITLE>Our Products</TITLE>
   <BASE href="http://www.aviary.com/products/intro.html">
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
   <P>Have you seen our <A href="../cages/birds.gif">Bird Cages</A>?
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

> the relative URI `"../cages/birds.gif"` would resolve to:
>
> `http://www.aviary.com/cages/birds.gif`

If not, there are only 2 options.

1. Leave the Jar in the same directory as the HTML.
2. Presuming that part of the script is the only thing you cannot change, add `codebase='../path/'` immediately after it, to tell the JRE to wherever the Jar is located.

As an aside:

```
CODE='com/synergex/My.class'
```

Should be:

```
CODE='com.synergex.My'
```